# Windows job scheduler still executing when time for next operation

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a Server 2008 scheduled job that does the following:

- Tests to see if the active/passive mscs service is running on this node.
- If so then maps a shared folder.
- Moves a bunch of fies from shared folder to clustered drive.
- Unmaps shared folder.

The job runs every 5 minutes. The files are procuded by another system and though not completley time critical delating the process much more than this is not acceptable to the business.

So far so good.
What I'm seeing is that although the script works correctly, the job history says that the second time it attempts to run the job, *'there is a previous copy of the job still running'*.

Does anyone have any thoughts on:
Why this is happening?
And how to go about debugging it?

If this were Unix/Linux this would not be a problem but this is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: Modify the script to log each task above into a log file so you'll know which one is taking too much time.

Comment: I think I have solved it by adding an 'exit' command at the end of the script. If someone can confirm that this is the right thing to do then I would appreciate it.